# Month and Year to standard format conversion

Tags: ios, date-conversion

I have month number and year separately,I want to convert them in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss +0000` format how can I do it.

I am trying the following code but it is not giving desired result.

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
 NSDateComponents *components = [NSDate componentsWithYear:year month:month day:1];  
 NSDate *date =  [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

when I am passing month as 8(Aug) and year as 2015 it is returning `3963801-06-02 18:30:00 +0000` .

The parameters I am passing, are in NSInteger.

Can anyone help.

Comment: That should work... did you try logging the year and the month values right before the second line?

Comment: Ya, the checked, at that point values are coming fine but after conversion only I am not getting the result.